# Python : how to use another method's returning value in another method?

Tags: python, methods

what i am trying to do is get a returning value from abcd method, and use this value to as a the substitue of fname and the error is continues to occur.

how can i fix this error?

ICB164000395.txt has four lines. 
and i want line_count print out 4(The number of lines in the text file)

```
class Test():
    def abcd(self):
        self.a = a
        a = 'ICB164000395.txt'
        return a


    def line_count(self, fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return i + 1
        print(i + 1)

t = Test()
t.line_count(abcd())
```

and the error appears like this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mg\Desktop\Tubuc\openAPI\test9.py", line 16, in 
    t.line_count(abcd(fname))
NameError: name 'abcd' is not defined

Comment: What is the error? Please include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: You're not providing a full file path so I assume the "error" is to do with not knowing where to look for your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the function:

```
def abcd(self):
    self.a = a
    a = 'ICB164000395.txt'
    return a
```

I'm guessign you're getting an error at `self.a = a` .. Because a is not defined yet. It's not passed in either.

I think what you want is:

```
class Test():
    def abcd(self):
        a = 'ICB164000395.txt' # you'll need to correct the path to this file
        return a


    def line_count(self, fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return i + 1
        print(i + 1)

t = Test()
t.line_count(t.abcd())
```

Answer (score 0):

`abcd` is an instance method so you have to call it from an instance of your class

```
t = Test()
t.line_cont(t.abcd())
```

Your `abcd` method also uses the variable `a` before it is ever defined, so you could change it to

```
def abcd(self):
    self.a = 'ICB164000395.txt'
    return self.a
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears what you want from your abcd method is typically handled in an init. You can set the file name when you instantiate a Test object. Then you can call the line count. Your line_count method should also specify how you are opening the file 'r' for read mode.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self._file_name = file_name


    def line_count(self):
        with open(self._file_name, 'r') as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return i + 1
        print(i + 1)

t = Test('ICB164000395.txt')
t.line_count()
```